# Subscription IDs unique across Users on Outlook's Notifications API?

Tags: outlook, notifications, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

After a successful subscription to a webhook, a subscription ID is generated. Are these unique across all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscription ID is unique (it's using as GUID which are designed for that specific purpose)